# Laravel display table record using query

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

This may be a silly question but I'm stuck..

I basically want to run a simple select query in laravel and show result from a single row in database result.

I'm new to php and laravel so trying to use model in this to get hang on MVC.

Following is what I have done.
Route

```
Route::get('groupprofile/(:any)',array('uses'=>'groups@profile'));
```

Controller - groups.php

```
class Groups_Controller extends Base_Controller {
    public $restful=true;
    public function get_profile($groupName){
        $groups=new Groups();
        $groupInfo=$groups->getGroupInfo($groupName);
        return View::make('groups.profile.groupprofile')->with('groupInfo',$groupInfo);
    }
}
```

Model - groups.php

```
class Groups{
    public function getGroupInfo($name){
        return DB::query('select * from Groups where name=?',array($name));
    }
}
```

View - groupprofile.blade.php

```
@layout('layouts.default')
@section('content')
<h1>This is a profile page for a group.</h1>
@foreach ($groupInfo -> results as $info)
    <br />Here I want to display all columns e.g. name, philosophy, founder name etc.
    <br />$info->Description
@endforeach
<br />Testing end

@endsection
```

Can someone please guide me how should I do this? 
I'm not able to understand how to display data from passed result set in view using blade.

Or is my approach wrong to do this? I'm more comfortable in writing queries so not using Eloquent or fluent query builder.

Answer (score 2):

Look at using Eloquent in Larvel, it's the ORM.  The [docs](http://four.laravel.com/docs/eloquent) are very good about this.

Your model should be Group.php

```
<?php class Group extends Eloquent {}
```

That's it!  Since we are extending Eloquent, we can now in our view pull a single row like this.

```
Group::where('name', '=', $somevar)->first()
```

Of course, you'll probably want to store that in a variable in your controller and pass the object to your view.

```
class Groups_Controller extends Base_Controller {
    public $restful=true;
    public function get_profile($groupName){
        $groupInfo = Group::where('name', '=', $groupName)->first()
        return View::make('groups.profile.groupprofile')->with('groupInfo',$groupInfo);
    }
}
```

Then in your view, you can access the properties (MySQL columns) of that row like this.

```
$groupInfo->name
```

Comment: Eloquent is slower than fluent though.

Comment: @itachi, he's pulling a single row.