# laravel how to get single row and post to view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

in MySql database i have systemSetting table and this have any data.

in this table i have this fields :

```
id  -  site_copyright -  date
```

i want to fill form with this single row.

```
{{ Form::model($siteSettings) }}

   {{ Form::label('site_copyright' , 'copy right') }}
   {{ Form::text('site_copyright', null , array('id'=>'site_copyright' )) }}

   {{ Form::label('site_copyright' , 'copy right') }}
   {{ Form::text('site_copyright', null , array('id'=>'site_copyright' )) }}

{{ Form::close() }}
```

**UPDATE:**
in CONTROLLER of that i have this:

```
public function getIndex()
{
    $siteSettings = SystemSetting::all();
    return  View::make('back_end.layouts.manageHeaders')->with('siteSettings', $siteSettings);
}
```

in Result, form could not parse data to `input` fields.

i get error for this :

```
   $siteSettings->site_copyright
```

Comment: You're calling a view on a model? Is that it?!

Comment: @DennisBraga i'm sorry. no thats controller

Comment: Please explain what error you are getting. The question seems to have been answered already, so you should either accept an answer or provide more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a duplicate of many questions, such as this: [Laravel display table record using query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16723984/laravel-display-table-record-using-query)

The short answer is: use `first()` method to get a single entry.

Comment: If you are looking for a row by its primary key then it might be a bit shorter
Model::find(id_here)

Answer (score 0):

You're using form model binding, so change your controller to:

```
public function getIndex()
{
    $siteSettings = new SystemSetting;
    return  View::make('back_end.layouts.manageHeaders', compact('siteSettings'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Query work on 5.1 or more

```
return DB::table('users')->where('id', $id)->value('field_name'); 

//if lower version of laravel like 4.2
DB::table('users')->where('id', $id)->pluck('field_name');
```